# Get token from cookie before sending it to client

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Owin.Security.Cookies and is creating an application cookie using:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(properties, identity);
```

Since the cookie is HttpOnly and I would also like to store the same token in somewhere else, how could I get it? I know I could make another http request and then read it, but I would like to access the token directly when signing in.

Is it possible and how could I do it?

Comment: Can't you query the request? `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies`

Comment: It looked like I can't access the Response Cookies in my method..I guess I need to return my IHttpActionResult first?

Comment: Correction: I can access it, but it´s empty